# Proof of a change of variables formula in integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, alternative-proof

The proof of following version of the Change of Variables Theorem in Integrals is not difficult:

"Let $\phi\colon [a,b]\to [\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ be a differentiable function such that $\phi'$ is integrable and $\phi(a)< \phi(b)$ and $f\colon [\phi(a),\phi(b)]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$; then $(f\circ \phi)\phi '$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_{[a,b]}(f\circ \phi)\phi'=\int_{[\phi(a),\phi(b)]}f$"

but I'm curious about the proof of the following version, where $f$ is assumed to be just integrable and not continuous:

"$\phi:[a,b]\to [\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ differentiable monotone increasing function such that $\phi '$ is Riemann integrable; $\ f\colon [\phi(a),\phi(b)]\to\mathbb{R}$  Riemann integrable function on $[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$. Then $(f\circ\phi)\phi '\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and $\int_{[a,b]}(f\circ\phi)\phi '=\int_{[\phi(a),\phi(b)]}f.$".

I read this last version on a real analysis book where the proof of this is given as a corollary of other theorems whose proofs span several pages and involve also the notion of Riemann-Stieltjes integral, so I'm wondering: does anyone know of a more elementary (i.e. not involving the notion of Riemann-Stieltjes integral but just the "usual" properties/theorems of Riemann integration)/shorter/etc. proof of this last theorem?

Comment: The first version has something weird in the way you define $\phi$. If you say $\phi(x)=x^2$, a=-1,b=1, then you are saying that $\phi:[-1,1]\to \{1\}$, aren't you? In the second version there is no problem since you assume $\phi$ is monotone.

Comment: Also note that if you only assume $\phi$ to be monotone you won't be able to talk about the derivative of $\phi$ everywhere. Nonetheless, a monotone function is differentiable almost everywhere (Except in a set of measure zero), and even without using that fact you can still define the Stieltjes integral $\int_I fd\phi$.

Comment: I still don't see why the first version should work (as stated) in the case $\phi$ is not monotone (Since the rank is not necessarily contained in that interval). You'd have to suppose $\phi([a,b)]\subseteq [\phi(a),\phi(b)]$.

Comment: About the second, no, I don't have a more elementary proof. But what I'm saying for the first is that as stated the function $\phi$ is not well defined. See the example of $\phi(x)=x^2$ above.

Comment: Well, the first thing is that there the hypothesis $\phi(a)<\phi(b)$ is a strict inequality. But now I understand that the hypothesis I said is added implicitly. 
Anyway, by Lebesgue Criterion, you can assume that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere and try to see where does the problem surge in the elementary proof.